# Why is the max integer in java 2^31 - 1 and not 2^31

Tags: java, memory, integer

Sorry if this is a really basic question, but why is there a minus one for the positive side?

Does it have to do with the zero being stored or something? I thought computing the highest possible decimal number for binary would just be to add the powers of two up, like for a 3 bit unsigned it would be

```
1*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^2 = 7
```

Shouldn't the same rule apply for java integers? Thanks

Comment: Because of [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement); see related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809044/how-many-values-can-be-represented-with-9-bits/3809058#3809058

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. We do "just add the powers of two up", in your example you are doing 1+2+ 4 which is same as 2^3 - 1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because Java can support max signed int as `0x7fffffff` which is 2^31-1.

```
2^31 = 0x80000000 is negative so Positive is 2^31-1
```

Binary level comparasion would be:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000  --> 2147483648 --> 2^31
01111111111111111111111111111111  --> 2147483647 --> 2^31 -1
^ Sign bit
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes it quite a bit more clear

Comment: "Signed bit" should be "Sign bit"

Comment: This is wrong. You have 32 bits, the 1 bit is used as sign bit, so you are left with 31 bits, but the question is not about the number of bits. The question is why the maximum is 2^31-1 and not the 2^31. This is because 2^31 is how many numbers you have, one of those numbers is 0 so the highest number becomes 2^31-1.

Answer (score 9):

The same rule does apply... `7` is `2^3 - 1`. And yes, it's because of the 0. :)

In contrast, negatives go to `-(2^31)`

So there's `2^31` negative numbers, one `0`, and `2^31-1` strict positives, which add to...

```
2^31 + 1 + 2^31 - 1 = 2 * 2^31 = 2^32
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because of the convenience of **two's complement** (which avoids storing two zeros), and Java stores numbers using that rapresentation. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 5):

There are `2^31` non-negative numbers ranging from `0` to `2^31-1`. So, yes, `zero` is stored as an integer, too. And also, there are `2^31` negative numbers ranging from `-2^31` to `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

It has to split up 2^32.
1/2 are negative.
0 counts with the positive.
In math 0 is neither negative nor positive.
It is consistent in .NET and MSSQL.

If you notice the set that does not include negatives is called unsigned.
It contains 0 and would not proper to call it positive.
Since the binary world starts at 0 it is kind of treated as positive.
The answer from Jack (+1) has why.

Comment: 0 is not considered positive, it's inserted between the positive numbers in two's complement just for a matter of convenience.

Comment: @NullUserException You are correct I just Wiki'd it and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have n bits you have 2^(n-1) negative numbers (as the top bit is a 1) and 2^(n-1) non-negative numbers.  As zero is a non-negative number you have up to 2^(n-1)-1 positive numbers which is also the maximum.

Note: there is no positive for the most negative number so

```
-Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Java integers are signed quantities, so one bit is reserved for the sign, leaving 31 bits for the value.