# 7-bit two's complement

Tags: bit, boolean-operations

Is there an easy way to figure this out? What is the lowest (most negative) number that can be represented by 7-bit two's complement? Show how to convert the number into its two's complement representation.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809044/how-many-values-can-be-represented-with-n-bits/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowest number is `-2^6`. To find a negative number's inverse in 2's complement (aka its absolute value) flip the bits and add one. So `(-1)*1000001 = 0111110+1 = 0111111 = 1000000 - 1 = 2^6-1`. As you can see there is a number lower than `1000001` and it is one less than it: `1000000`. Finding it's absolute value we get:

`(-1)*(100000) = (-1)*(100001-1) = (-1)*(100001) + 1 = (2^6-1)+1 = 2^6`.

Comment: Your ranges are a bit large for 7 bits.