# Completing a list of possible binary sequences give a binary sequence with gaps

Tags: scilab

So, I am working on a program in Scilab which solves a binary puzzle. I have come across a problem however. Can anyone explain to me the logic behind solving a binary sequence with gaps (like [1 0 -1 0 -1 1 -1] where -1 means an empty cell. I want all possible solutions of a given sequence. So far I have:

```
function P = mogelijkeCombos(V)
for i=1:size(V,1)
    if(V(i) == -1)
        aantalleeg = aantalleeg +1
    end
end
for i=1:2^aantalleeg 
    //creating combos here
end
endfunction
```

sorry that some words are in dutch
aantalleeg means amountempty by which I mean the amount of empty cells
I hope I gave you guys enough info. I don't need any code written, I'd just like ideas of how I can make every possible rendition as I am completely stuck atm.

BTW this is a school assignment, but the assignment is way bigger than this and it's just a tiny part I need some ideas on

ty in advance

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You could create the combos by extending your code and create all possible binary words of the length "amountempty" and replacing them bit-for-bit in the empty cells of V.

### **Step-by-step description**

- Find all the empty cell positions
- Count the number of positions you've found (which equals the number of empty cells)
- Create all possible [binary numbers](http://l3d.cs.colorado.edu/courses/CSCI1200-96/binary.html) with the length of your count
- For each binary number you generate, place the bits in the empty cells
- print out / store the possible sequence with the filled in bits

### **Example**

**Find all the empty cell positions**

You could for example check from left-to-right starting at 1 and if a cell is empty add the position to your position list.

```
V = [1 0 -1 0 -1 1 -1] 
          ^    ^    ^
          |    |    | 
     1 2  3 4  5 6  7

// result
positions = [3 5 7]
```

**Count the number of positions you've found**

```
//result 
amountempty = 3;
```

**Create all possible binary numbers with the length amountempty**

You could create all possible numbers or words with the [`dec2bin`](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/dec2bin.html) function in SciLab. The number of possible words is easy to determine because you know [how much separate values can be represented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809044/how-many-values-can-be-represented-with-n-bits) by a word of amountempty bits long.

```
// Create the binary word of amountEmpty bits long
binaryWord = dec2bin( i, amountEmpty );
```

The binaryWord generated will be a string, you will have to [split it](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.0/en_US/strsplit.html) into separate bits and [convert it to numbers](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.0/en_US/evstr.html).

**For each binaryWord you generate**

Now create a possible solution by starting with the original V and fill in every empty cell at the position from your position list with a bit from binaryWordPerBit

```
possibleSequence = V;

for j=1:amountEmpty
    possibleSequence( positions(j) ) = binaryWordPerBit(j);              
end
```

I wish you "veel succes met je opdracht"